# How to template with JSP files

Tags: php, html, templates, jsp

I'm learning JSP and have a good working knowledge of PHP and MVC frameworks.

I would like to know how I can break down JSP files so that I can have a file for the header, with the doctype/meta/references stuff, a file for the footer with the closing body and html tags etc, and a file for the menu (these sections will be the same on every page so I don't want to duplicate them, otherwise updating will take ages).

In PHP I would just include the file for each.

How does this work for JSP, and is there a best practise?

Comment: You might be better off jumping straight to JSF for this. Much less time writing boilerplate code, more time writing value-added code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with what Matt said in his comment, but if you really want to do included JSP files using

```
<jsp:include page="<yourfile>"/>
```

works about how you'd expect, where yourfile is either an actual path to a specific file, or a file in the same directory.

Comment: you forgot to add the / to close the tag. Otherwise it does not compile: <jsp:include page="<yourfile>" />

Answer (score 0):

Doing this stuff manually is messy. Try [Apache Tiles](http://tiles.apache.org/index.html) or [Sitemesh](http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/).

Comment: Sadly, as of 2011 Sitemesh is no longer maintained.